# Error with p: schema url

Tags: xml, spring

Im seeting properties on my applicationContext like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

but im getting this error on my schema reference for p:

```
Error: File not found in the specified address : http://www.springframework.org/schema/p
```

did the url change or something?

Comment: Impossible to tell from such a fragment. Also, you do not say where you get the error from (system startup, or an external XML validator, for example).

Comment: i get it when i save the xml file, i also checked the url and it gives 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the content "xmlns : http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" from the xml file where the corresponding bean definition is mentioned by you. This error is getting generated because of the absence of the 'p' folder in 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/p' on the web, The Xsd's inside the P folder is been removed by Spring community.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete. If you just remove the content you're suggesting form the xml, the p namespace will no longer be valid. What do you replace it with? Otherwise I'm getting the error "The prefix "p" for attribute "p:username" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound"

Comment: As p namespace cannot be used , because of the above mentioned reason. You can use 'jdbc' in the place of 'p' in context.xml. But you also need to include xsi :schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/" in your xml metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML validator tries to fetch that file and fails. The latter is no wonder since it is not a file name or URL, but just the name of a namespace. The former, however, is not correct, since, well, it is not a file name or URL, but just the name of a namespace, and an XML validator should not even try to fetch it.

I suspect you did not define the namespace correctly, but it is impossible to tell from such a fragment.